# If $k$ is an odd number then $3k^2 +16$ is not a perfect cube

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, cubics

> Show that if $k$ is odd then $3k^2+16$ is not a perfect cube.

Could anybody please prove it?  I am particularly interested in a proof that mostly relies on divisibility.

Comment: Note that for odd $x$ we have $x^3\equiv x$ modulo both $12$ and $24$ because little Fermat gives $x^3\equiv x$ mod $3$ and for odd $x$ we have $x^2\equiv 1$ modulo $8$.

Write $k=2r+1$ to obtain $12r^2+12r+19=s^3$ for some $s$. Mod $24$ this is reduces to $19\equiv s^3$, whence from the previous observation $s\equiv 19 \mod 24$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are looking for integral solutions to $3k^2+16=m^3$, with $k$ odd. Substituting $k$ and $m$ by
$$k:=\frac{8}{9}y+\frac{4}{9}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad m:=\frac{4}{3}x,$$
and multiplying through by $\frac{27}{64},$ we find that any integral solution yields a rational solution to
$$y^2+y=x^3-7,$$
which just so happens to be an equation for an elliptic curve over $\Bbb{Q}$, in minimal Weierstrass form.

This elliptic curve over $\Bbb{Q}$ has [two nontrivial points](http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/?label=%5B0,0,1,0,-7%5D&jump=label%20or%20isogeny%20class), which are $(3,4)$ and $(3,-4)$, corresponding to the integral solutions $(k,m)=(4,4)$ and $(k,m)=(-4,4)$. These are then the only integral solutions to the original equation, and in particular there are no solutions if $k$ is odd.